# How do I make a HTML canvas rectangle resize along with mouse drag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I am creating a web-based annotation application for annotating images via the HTML canvas element and Javascript. I would like the user to mouse down to indicate the start of the rectangle, drag to the desired end coordinate and let go to indicate the opposite end of the rectangle.

Currently, I am able to take the starting coordinates and end coordinates to create a rectangle on the image with the *context.rects()* function, however as I am uncertain on how to resize a specific rectangle on the canvas, that leaves me with the rectangle only being drawn after the user has released the mouse click.

How would I be able to resize a specific rectangle created onmousedown while dragging?

The following is the code snippet that performs the function:

```
var isMouseDown = false;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) { 
        if(annMode){
            isMouseDown = true;
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            startX = parseInt(e.pageX - offset.left);
            startY = parseInt(e.pageY - offset.top);
        }
    };
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) { 
        if(isMouseDown) { 
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var intermediateX = parseInt(e.pageX - offset.left);
            var intermediateY = parseInt(e.pageY - offset.top);
            console.log(intermediateX);
        } 
    };
    canvas.onmouseup   = function(e) { 
        if(annMode&&isMouseDown){
            isMouseDown = true;
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var endX = parseInt(e.pageX - offset.left);
            var endY = parseInt(e.pageY - offset.top);
            var width = endX - startX;
            var height = endY - startY;
            context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
            context.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
            context.stroke();
        }
        isMouseDown = false 
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my handy-front-end scripts come in handy!

As I understood the question, you wanted to be able to move your mouse to any point on the canvas, hold the left mouse button, and drag in any direction to make a rectangle between the starting point and any new mouse position. And when you release the mouse button it will stay.

Scripts that will help you accomplish what you are trying to do:

https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end/blob/master/README.md#canvasjs
https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end/blob/master/README.md#pointerjs

Both scripts just makes the code a lot cleaner and easier to understand, so I used those.

Here is a fiddle as simple as you can make it really using

`const canvas = new Canvas([]);`

and

`const mouse = new Pointer();`

https://jsfiddle.net/0y8cbao3/

Did I understand your question correctly?

Do you want a version with comments describing every line and what is does?

There are still some bugs at the moment but im going to fix those soon!

**EDIT**

After reading your questions again, I reacted to: "...however as I am uncertain on how to resize a specific rectangle on the canvas...".

Canvas is like an image. Once you have drawn to it, you can NOT "resize" different shapes. You can only clear the whole canvas and start over (ofcourse you can clear small portions too).

That's why the Canvas helper is so helpful. To be able to "animate" the canvas, you have to create a loop that redraws the canvas with a new frame each 16ms (60 fps).

Comment: js fiddle doesnt do resizable rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The `canvas` API does not preserve references to specific shapes drawn with it (unlike SVG). The `canvas` API simply provides convenient functions to apply operations to the individual pixels of the `canvas` element.

You have a couple options to achieve a draggable rectangle:

1. You can position a styled `div` over your canvas while the user is dragging. Create a container for your canvas and the `div`, and update the position and size the `div`. When the user releases, draw your rectangle. Your container needs to have `position: relative` and the `div` needs to be absolutely positioned. Ensure the div has a higher `z-index` than the `canvas`.

   In your mouse down method, set `div.style.display` to `block`. Then update the position (`style.left`, `style.top`, `style.width`, and `style.height`) as the mouse is dragged. When the mouse is released, hide it again (`style.display = 'none'`).
2. You can manually store references to each item you want to draw, clear the canvas (`context.clearRect`), and redraw each item on the canvas each frame. This kind of setup is usually achieved through recursive usage of the `window.requestAnimationFrame` method. This method takes a callback and executes on the next draw cycle of the browser.

The first option is probably easier to achieve in your case. If you plan to expand the capabilities of your app further, the 2nd will provide more versatility. A basic loop would be implemented as so:

```
// setup code, create canvas & context

function mainLoop() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /** do your logic here and re-draw **/

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function startApp() {
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}
```

This tutorial has detailed explanation of event loops for HTML canvas: http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing

I also have a fully featured implementation on my GitHub that's part of rendering engine I wrote: https://github.com/thunder033/mallet/blob/master/src/mallet/webgl/webgl-app.ts#L115